# Assign ENUM type to constructor

Tags: java, enums, constructor

```
String model;
int year;
enum Color {GREEN, BLUE, RED}; 
double price;
```

Color shade;

```
public Car(String model, int year, Color shade, double price) {

    this.model = model;
    this.year = year; 
    this.shade= shade;
    this.price = price;
}
```

Is this ok? still gives error when i acctually make the object with the main method.

Comment: No, you didn't. Thats not know enums work. You have declared a type, you didn't define an instance.

Comment: hey, so how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

This syntax  :  `this.Color = shade;`
refers an instance field named `Color` in the `Car` class.
But you don't have any `Color` field in the `Car` class.

This :

```
enum Color {GREEN, BLUE, RED};
```

is the enum class declaration.

Just introduce a field in `Car` to be able to assign to it a `Color` :

```
public class Car {
    String model;
    int year;
    Color color;
...
    public Car(String model, int year, Color shade, double price) {
      this.model = model;
      this.year = year;
      this.color = shade;
      this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh got it! Problem fixed thanks alot for the help :)

Comment: @DannyBorisOv if this answer solved your problem, you might consider accepting it to reward the answerer and let future visitors know what the right answer is.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Color {GREEN, BLUE, RED} ;

public class Car{

    String m_model;
    int m_year;
    Color m_color;
    double m_price;

    public Car(String model, int year, Color shade, double price) {

        this.m_model = model;
        this.m_year = year; 
        this.m_color = shade;
        this.m_price = price;

        System.out.println("A new Car has been created!");
    }


    static public void main(String[] args)
    {

        Car car = new Car("Ferrari", 2017, Color.RED, 350000);
    }
}
```